# What does the phrase "it does not become you" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I have heard it used in a negative sense. For example, "rudeness does not become you" etc.

Is this phrase used in a positive context as well? (like "generosity becomes you")?

Comment: The most notable use of this verb in the positive is perhaps the 1992 (I think) movie ***Death Becomes Her***, starring Goldie Hawn, Meryl Streep, and Bruce Willis. Highly recommended.

Comment: As others have answered, one meaning of "becoming" is "to look well". But it is a dated use belonging in an age and society more concerned with an image of gentility. [Prince Andrew was recently derided in the media for having described his late friend Jeffrey  Epstein as having engaged in "conduct unbecoming"](https://www.newyorker.com/news/letter-from-the-uk/prince-andrews-noxious-interview-about-jeffrey-epstein) - the allegations against Epstein having involved child prostitution and sex trafficking on an industrial scale.

Comment: "Fatherhood becomes you." --Star Trek, it means "Fatherhood fits with you" or "it's natural for you."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

becoming can mean the obvious - changing into, growing into, happening, coming about.
It also has a second meaning - "to look well"

The word started to be used in this manner in the early 14th century, from the earlier sense of "to agree with, be fitting" (early 13th century).

Similarly there is "comely", which means handsome, lovely, splendid.

Therefore, "generosity *becomes* you" means "generosity *looks well on/is fitting on* you" (essentially, it makes you look good).  "Rudeness does *not become* you" means "rudeness does *not look well on/does not fit* you" (essentially, it makes you look bad).

You can also use the word *"unbecoming"* as a negative. "Your rudeness is *unbecoming*."

Answer (score 1):

Become is being used in the sense of "suits you"...e.g., crime does not become you (i.e., you're a crappy criminial), "that dress becomes you" (you look good in it) etc.

It's in the [dictonary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/become) as a second definition.

Comment: "Crime does not become you" doesn't really imply that you're bad at crime (assuming that's what you meant by "crappy criminal"), the meaning is more that engaging in crime is not appropriate behaviour.